# Is this a correct way of Navigating a Page inside of a Frame, which also in another Page Frame? (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So in this image, which contains a frame, where pages should show (Pages with Current Display are current source of Parent Page)

[image]

and I found this [repository](https://github.com/SamTheDev/SampleMvvmLightNavigation/tree/master/SampleNavigationMvvmLight), just to use the navigation service
however, it only uses `RootFrame`. so I made some changes

```cs
// INavigationService.cs
interface INavigationService
{
    string CurrentPageKey { get; }

    void GoBack();
    void NavigateTo(string frame, string pageKey);
    void NavigateTo(string frame, string pageKey, object parameter);
}

// FrameNavigationService.cs
public virtual void NavigateTo(string frameName, string key, object parameter)
{
    ...

    if(GetDescendantFromName(Application.Current.MainWindow, frameName) is Frame frame)

    ...
}
```

and used this code:

```
// MainViewModel
public RelayCommand LoadPage1Command 
            => loadPage1Command ?? (loadPage1Command = new RelayCommand(() => navigationService.NavigateTo("Page1")));

// Page1ViewModel
public RelayCommand LoadedCommand
            => loadedCommand ?? (loadedCommand = new RelayCommand(() => navigationService.NavigateTo("Page1_Frame", "Page1_1")));
```

I can't tell if that's the way of navigating a page inside of a frame.
Are there any behavior design patterns I could use as alternative to this if the modified code is bad?

Comment: Any reason for frames? Content Control and a DataTemplate would solve this with no navigation service. Seems like a big overkill for something that can be solved a lot easier.

Comment: I only use frames for displaying Pages. I'm not familiar on using ContentControl and DataTemplate until now